# Using XML-derived Variables in the Main Method

Tags: java, xml, variables, static, main-method

so I am making a game where the player's skill damage is determined by their Skill Level and their weapon Mastery. The two values are stored in an XML document, and I am using DOM to retrieve the values, and am trying to print their sum to the console.

```
public class Damage {

    public String skillName = "Bash"; //name of the skill

    Xml config = new Xml("C:/character.xml","config");//part of the XML retrieving
    Xml version = config.child("Character");//another part of the XML retrieving

    int mastery = version.integer("Mastery"); //mastery of the skill
    int skillLevel = version.integer("skillName");//skill level 
    int skillDamage = mastery + skillLevel; //adding the two values together

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println(skillDamage);
}

}
```

When I run this code, it tells me that I can't have non-static variables in the static Main method. However, when I place the static tag before the int on the variables, it results in 0.

My question is: How can I make the variables static but still produce the sum of the two XML values? Could I somehow collect the non-static data from the XML, make it static, and then use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(new Damage().skillDamage);
```

Because you need a instance for non-static class-variables

Comment: You are right. Thought it was inside a method in my haste. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of your Damage class first, if you want to use its non-static variables/members. Put your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Damage dmg = new Damage();

    System.out.println(dmg.skillDamage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want the variables to be static.

1) Make skillDamage a `public int`

2) Then, just create your object in your main method:

```
Damage d = new Damage();
System.out.println(d.skillDamage);
```

It would probably be best to encapsulate skillDamage in a method, something like

```
public int getSkillDamage(){...}
```

Comment: +1 for inheritance-save getter. But if you use non-final getter: the field should be private/protected then.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have class `cow`. You can create instances of that class, for example `berta` and `milka` . That would mean, that you have two cows and their behaviour is based on class `cow`.

If you define something `static` it means, it is `static` to its `class`, therefore you can not define specific actions for each cow.

You should have a new class, for example "GameEngine", you should have all what you need there and you should create it with something like : `GameEngine ge = new GameEngine();` and then use methods like `ge.readXML();`